# image tap fired twice

Tags: image, events, richtextbox, windows-phone-7.1, tap

I have a simple code, with a rich textbox  which has an image in it, and the image tap event is fired twice.

How can I fix this?

The code:

```
    <RichTextBox>
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Image Source="/PhoneApp1;component/someimage.jpg" tap="image_OnTap" />
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void image_OnTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true;  // <- The mark has completed the process,
   MessageBox.Show ("ok");
}
```